# whats wrong with this code? im trying to change the height of each section to the height of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

whats wrong with this code? im trying to change the height of each section to the height of window.

```
function setsize()
 {
var w=$(window).width();
var h=$(window).height();
var sections = new Array("home","about","skills");
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(sections[i]);
        $(element).height(h);
    }

}
$(window).ready(function() {
    setsize(); 
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    setsize();
});
```

here is sample of the  markup:

```
    <section id="#home">
                                    <h1>..................</h1>

    </header>
```

Comment: EDIT: THE ABOVE CODE WORKS FINE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a strange way to do that ?

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
    $('#home, #about, #skills').height( $(this).height() );
});
```

You have to update the variables when the window changes size, i.e. inside the resize function

**EDIT:**

You'll also need a DOM ready handler, and window.onload isn't always triggered when doing it that way, so just do the same thing on DOM ready, like so :

```
$(function() {
    $('#home, #about, #skills').height( $(window).height() );
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('#home, #about, #skills').height( $(this).height() );
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zTFKa/)

Comment: It does - check the fiddle.

Comment: I didn't really debug your code at all, I just wrote something else as your code looked a little weird, but looking at it now, it should actually work, and it seems to do -> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTFKa/1/)